# ¿alguna idea sobre error, el equipo de destino denegó expresamente(...) IIS7?

Tags: c#, iis, webforms

Saludos! pues llevo rato dando vueltas el porque de este error sin encontrar solución aun, alguien tiene una idea más puntual de lo que puede estar pasando?

```
No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión 127.0.0.1:63432
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, este es un webservice al que debo enviarle un string xml por Post y en el servidor de pruebas funciona Ok, pero lo pase a desarrollo y ya no quiere funcionar, pues según parece el servidor me está rechazando la conexión, pero no se porque está usando esa dirección 127.0.0.1 (localhost) si en ningún lado he especificado eso. ¿Qué se ha probado?
Ingrese al servidor y en el navegador escribo localhost o 127.0.0.1 y me da error 404, tendrá esto algo que ver?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Ya cambié Bindings en el IIS Ya verifiqué el Web.Config
2. Ya verifiqué el String xml Ya probé agregando excepciones en firewall
3. Ya probé agregar excepcion de conexion en el IIS
4. Ya probe deshabilitando el SSL
5. Ya probé apuntando a la IP 192.168.99.77 en vez de www.(...).com
6. Ya probé apuntando desde pruebas a desarrollo
7. Ya probé apuntar desde desarrollo a pruebas (funciona)
8. Ya verifique Firewall y antivirus, no es.
9. Reinicie los servicios Net.Pipe, Net.TCP (estaban iniciados)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿O será que es necesario que el sitio de desarrollo esté ubicado en ¿DefaultSite?

Anexo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Nota reciente: (20171120 9:29am GMT-5) me he dado cuenta que si deshabilito el URL rewrite para que no exija el certificado SSL, arroja el mismo error, osea con https: arroja error y con http: no lo arroja pero porque redireccionaba al https y perdía el string xml, y si se carga directamente el webservice sin pasarle la string no arroja error pero claro no hace nada porque no tiene string.
- Nota reciente (20171120 15:15 GMT-5), me he dado cuenta que el servidor de desarrollo el IIS express usa esa IP 127.0.0.1:63432, no se es que tiene que ver el PC de desarrollo con el de producción?.
- Nota (20171121 08:40 GMT-5), es posible que sea cuestion de los bindings, están de la siguiente manera. ¿afecta el orden?
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes subir como tienes la configuracion; Click derecho sobre el sitio > Administrar sitio web > condiguracion avanzada, porfa sube esa imagen para ver como tienes la configuracion.

Comment: prueba a acceder por Ip en vez de por localhost a ver si te funciona

Comment: Listo compa Gabriel, ahí puse la imagen. Compa @miguel, ya lo probé con 127.0.0.1 o localhost es igual.

Comment: Mira las respuestas en esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it/14079317

Comment: Gracias @Luis No encontré mucho y lo que encontré ya lo probé, sigue pasando lo mismo.

Comment: Si tienes habilitado solo el protocolo https como se ve en la configuración tienes que tener un certificado aun que sea de desarrollo también en el load no se si del web service o de tu pagina hace la conexión al equipo local y a ese puerto en particular si estas consumiendo un servicio local puedes hacer un telnet y ver si esta andando. Cuando estamos en desarrollo y usamos el iis express desde visual studio es cuando tenemos rutas como las que indicas si es así deberías mover el servicio al iis

Comment: Te recomiendo que a nivel código busques si no esta una ruta con puerto especifico como hardcode, algo así; string ruteForm = "https://localhost:44320/; Espero que encuentres la solución @Vulpex

Answer (score 2):

intenta usar la url completa del Web Service, es decir, incluyendo al inicio https:// o http:// según sea el caso original.

Una vez tuve error en una conexión por esto y también por la diferencia de horarios con el servidor de destino.

Es probable que sea porque busca el Web Service /ServidorProcesosOnLine dentro de localhost si no le pone el protocolo (http o https) con la dirección completa. Tal vez por eso le funcionaba de forma local.

Saludos y espero que encuentre pronto la solución.

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia, pero no, nada, sigue completamente igual, no importa si es ruta relativa estática, con www. sin www. con https: sin https o solamente http, arroja exactamente el mismo error. `No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión 127.0.0.1:63432`

Answer (score 2):

Revisa tu web.config y donde esta el puerto agregale el puerto, en mi caso lo corregi colocando 30390 ya que tenia otro 17850

Comment: Hola @Ivan. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte... Teniendo en cuenta que es una pregunta de hace más de 4 meses, si bien está genial que agregues una posible solución, sería bueno intentar *explicar* cuándo fallaría el puerto por omisión, en qué caso concreto, y qué hacer en ese caso. Además, no entiendo qué significa "*ya que tenia otro 17850*".

Comment: creo que @Ivan se refiere es en la configuración de los puertos de IIS. Muchas veces sucede que el localhost al que estar queriendo tiene en configuración un puerto distinto al que te da IIS Express (en mi caso) por lo tanto al querer acceder los puertos son distintos y marca ese error. Saludos! [![Puertos IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh5pg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh5pg.png)